# Calling a Java variadic function from C through the JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am currently working on creating some Java bindings for a C library I work on. One of our C-structs has a char buffer that is a file system path. After calling the C function, the buffer is correctly populated. I want to take the buffer and convert it to a `java.nio.file.Path` member on the Java object.

I am having some trouble however. I for some reason am generating a `NullPointerException` within C, and I can't really see the problem.

The way to create a `java.nio.file.Path` object is going through [`java.nio.file.Paths::get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-).

Here is the relevant C code:

```c
const jclass paths_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/nio/file/Paths");
if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
    return;
const jmethodID get_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(
    env, paths_class, "get", "(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/file/Path;");
if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
    return;
const jstring path_str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, info.mi_path);
if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
    return;
const jobject path_obj =
   (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, paths_class, get_method, path_str); // exception generated here
if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
    return;
```

And the Java class for good measure:

```java
public final class MclassInfo {
    private native void _get(final Kvdb kvdb, Mclass mclass) throws HseException;

    private long allocatedBytes;
    private long usedBytes;
    private Path path;

    MclassInfo(final Kvdb kvdb, final Mclass mclass) throws HseException {
        _get(kvdb, mclass);
    }

    public long getAllocatedBytes() {
        return allocatedBytes;
    }

    public long getUsedBytes() {
        return usedBytes;
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

All I can think is that somehow I am not calling the Java variadic function properly. I have also tried passing `NULL` as an extra argument to the method call, but ended up with the same issue.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Which statement causes the NPE? What does your IDE show you when you step through the code?

Comment: Jim, having a hard time getting a stack trace with regard to this specific situation of running tests through Maven and connecting to the process via gdb. I will need to keep working at it. Any resources you may have would also be valuable. Going to try what answer has suggested however in the meantime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you are trying to invoke is declared as `get(String first, String... more)`. The variadic syntax in Java is just sugar for an array of the specified type, i.e. the *two* arguments of this method are really `String` and `String[]` -- which you correctly coded in the `GetStaticMethodID` call as `(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)`.

So to call it **you need *two* arguments: one `String` and one `String[]` (array)** -- and (for your case) the array must contain zero elements, but such an empty array is *not* the same as NULL. Have a gander at `NewObjectArray`.

Comment: Wow. This was definitely the fix. I guess what wasn't clear to me was that a zero-element array is not the same as NULL. I had thought about trying it, but thought against it since it seemed weird that I would need to create a zero element array. In retrospect, I should've given it a shot. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @tristan957 An array of zero elements needs to protect users from Null Pointer Exception. Dereference a zero element array is a no-operstion, but dereference a Null Pointer is undefined behavior exception.